# What is the word for a person who does animal husbandry?

Tags: single-word-requests

As the question says, is there a word for a person who is into the profession of management and care of animals for profit.

Comment: Cattleman: (Agriculture) US and Canadian a person who owns or rears cattle on a large scale, usually for beef.

Comment: Animal husband?

Comment: At what level is this person working? For example, is s/he the proprietor of a horse farm or a sheep farm, or someone employed by the farm to tend the animals? The kind of animal may also matter; someone who breeds show dogs, for instance, would be a *breeder* whereas someone who produces milk would be a *dairy farmer*.

Comment: In the United States, _rancher_ is understood to refer to someone who raises animals (usually cattle, although _sheep rancher_ is not unheard of) for profit on a large plot of rural land. People who own smaller plots of land tend to be called _farmers_, sometimes further qualified by the category of animal or animal product they produce—for example, _dairy farmer_ (as choster points out above) or _chicken farmer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stockman)...

> **stockman**
>    **1.** (Agriculture)
>    **a.** *a man engaged in the rearing or care of **farm livestock**, esp cattle*
>
> **livestock**
>    **1.** (Agriculture) (functioning as singular or plural)
>    *cattle, horses, poultry, and similar animals kept for domestic use (not as pets), esp on a farm or ranch*

Answer (score 5):

I think [farmer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/farmer) is a general term that may fit your description: You usually need to specify the breed like, cattle farmer,  sheep farmer, pig farmer etc.

> - (Agriculture) a person who operates or manages a farm.
> - A [farmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer) (also called an agriculturer) is a person engaged in agriculture, raising living organisms for food or raw materials. The term usually applies to people who do some combination of raising field crops, orchards, vineyards, poultry, or other livestock.

Source: www.en.wikipedia.org

Comment: At least in the Midwest of the U.S. and despite the dictionary definition, I think most people think of a farmer as someone who cultivates the land and grows crops, not someone who raises animals, which is what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., they are often called *livestock producers.* There is a [National Livestock Producers Association](http://www.nlpa.org/), which is an organization with 215,000 beef, dairy, hog, sheep and goat producers as members.

Then it can be broken down into more specific types of producers: *cattle producers, dairy producers, pork producers, goat producers, poultry producers,* etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Husbandman**. From The Bible, King James Version:

> **Jeremiah 51:23** I will also break in pieces with thee the shepherd and his flock; and with thee will I break in pieces the husbandman and his yoke of oxen; and with thee will I break in pieces captains and rulers.

> **Zechariah 13:5** But he shall say, I am no prophet, I am an husbandman; for man taught me to keep cattle from my youth.

Comment: The dictionary definition for "husbandman" is "farmer" (from http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/husbandman?s=t), with reference to its biblical use as "one who cultivates the ground", so unfortunately this doesn't seem like a good option to distinguish between a crop-grower and an animal-raiser.

Comment: Hmm...Yeah, I can see now that distinction is lost in translation (Genesis 4:2 And she further bore his brother Abel. And Abel was a shepherd, but Cain was a husbandman.) Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is **fancier**.

> **[fan·ci·er](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fancier)** /ˈfansēər/ *noun*
>
> a connoisseur or enthusiast of something, especially someone who has a
>   special interest in or breeds a particular animal.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is cattle man, herdsman, cowherd, goatherd or cowboy.

[cattleman synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cattleman)

[cattleman meaning from dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cattleman)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a person responsible for healthy management of the animals (both livestock and wild) on a noble's property, ***steward*** would be an appropriate term.

Comment: If someone said they were a steward, I'd ask them which airline they work on—I've never heard steward used this way and it's certainly not the definition people are going to think of when they hear the word.

Comment: Probably just the fantasy/history nerd in me and religious nerdisms of my friends. I think of the Denathor II, the steward of Gondor (Lord of the Rings) who's job it is to care for and manage the kingdom until the return of the monarch. Some of my friends will reference our (mankind's) responsibility as stewards of this world.